# OpenStreetMap (OSM): How to create map where website visitors can add places?

Tags: openstreetmap

I just need some links, where to begin. I am not really familiar with OSM, but I want to create little website with a world map, where visitors of my site can simply add places with a descriptopn. I don't know where to start. Are there any pre-coded templates for a CMS like Wordpress or just non-CMS templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org). There is a [QuickStart Tutorial](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) on how to add a map. If you want to add a [Marker](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html) by a click on the map have a look at [ClickHandlers](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Click-js.html) (example can be seen [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/click.html)). What you would have to change is showing a field onClick, where the user can enter the description. What could be also from interest for you is the [OpenLayers.Popup](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html).

If the result should be stored, you have to save the description and marker position into a database, so you probably will need some server side implementation for your idea.